# Error with Gyrobot project for android in Github

Tags: android, eclipse, android-styles

The other day I wanted to run this code from the [Gyrobot](https://github.com/divyanshusrivastava/Gyrobot) package and I faced Some Errors!

Here is the file Eclipse Has problem with:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
</resources>
```

And Here is the ERROR:

```
C:\Users\Logic\Desktop\Gyrobot-master\Gyrobot-master\android\harald\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Check the targetSdkVersion in manifest.

Comment: @bigdestroyer Can you Run the project yourself??